# how to put button on top of android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout?

Tags: android

I'm having a button that is on top of `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`
but the button stays behind it in the layout display and on the device
how do i put the button in front of it ?

or in a different question how do i add a button next to the on screen options menu on the upper right side ?

here is my Layout XML >

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="apps.radwin.wintouch.activities.alignmentActivities.WorkordersSelectionActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_workorders_selection">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/filterButtonMainWorkorderSelection"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_filter_list_black_24dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="30dp" />



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsLayoutWorkorderSelection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/workorderSelectionMainViewPagerContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/add_workorders_plus"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:background="#293339"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_showAllText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="SHOW ALL"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:id="@+id/filter_menu_workorders_show_all"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_showAllCheckMark"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_showAllTextLine"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_showAllText"
                    ></View>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_alarm_black_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedImage"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_showAllTextLine"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/filter_menu_workorders_planned"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_showAllTextLine"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Planned"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedText"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedImage"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedImage" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_PlannedCheckMark"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedText"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_cloud_off_black_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_incompleteImage"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedImage"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/filter_menu_workorders_incomplete"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedImage"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Uncompleted"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_intompleteText"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_incompleteImage"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_incompleteImage" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_IncompleteCheckMark"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_intompleteText"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_cloud_queue_black_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_CompleteImage"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_incompleteImage"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/filter_menu_workorders_complete"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_incompleteImage"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="complete 5"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_completeText"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_CompleteImage"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_CompleteImage" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_completeCheckMark"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_completeText"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp" />



                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_CompleteImage"
                    ></View>


            </RelativeLayout>



        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I want a custom button to draw above the AppBarLayout and not collapse with it...

Comment: can you add screen shot of the layout?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your button inside a cardview and give some elevation to the cardview. I tried the below code: (Used Textview instead of Button)

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/filterButtonMainWorkorderSelection"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_flash_auto_black_24dp"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TO PLACE BUTTON AT THE TOP OF APPBARLAYOUT**

In your layout you are using the Toolbar, it takes top position of your layout. If you want ***Button*** on the top of toolbar then.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/filterButtonMainWorkorderSelection"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_filter_list_black_24dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="30dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsLayoutWorkorderSelection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

if you want it below the **Toolbar** then place the **Button** below the Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

you used Toolbar in your layout, this takes top position of your layout. If you want Button on the top of toolbar then place the button between the `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>` tag. like this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/filterButtonMainWorkorderSelection"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_filter_list_black_24dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsLayoutWorkorderSelection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

This should give you the desired result

Answer (score 0):

There could be two issues on why the button is not displayed, ordering and elevation.

Your toolbar could have the default elevation which is `4dp`.

So I would suggest you try to do:

1. Move the button position to after your `AppBarLayout`
2. Add elevation higher than the `Toolbar`, to note, it doesn't matter the ordering you put your views if the issue is the elevation.

I've made both changes (elevation to 6dp) below so you can simply copy paste your layout file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="apps.radwin.wintouch.activities.alignmentActivities.WorkordersSelectionActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_workorders_selection">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsLayoutWorkorderSelection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/filterButtonMainWorkorderSelection"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_filter_list_black_24dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/workorderSelectionMainViewPagerContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/add_workorders_plus"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:background="#293339"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_showAllText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="SHOW ALL"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:id="@+id/filter_menu_workorders_show_all"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_showAllCheckMark"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_showAllTextLine"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_showAllText"
                    ></View>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_alarm_black_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedImage"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_showAllTextLine"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/filter_menu_workorders_planned"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_showAllTextLine"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Planned"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedText"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedImage"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedImage" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_PlannedCheckMark"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedText"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_cloud_off_black_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_incompleteImage"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedImage"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/filter_menu_workorders_incomplete"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_plannedImage"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Uncompleted"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_intompleteText"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_incompleteImage"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_incompleteImage" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_IncompleteCheckMark"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_intompleteText"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_cloud_queue_black_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_CompleteImage"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_incompleteImage"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/filter_menu_workorders_complete"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_incompleteImage"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="complete 5"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_completeText"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_CompleteImage"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_CompleteImage" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_completeCheckMark"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_completeText"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp" />



                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/workorderFilterPopup_CompleteImage"
                    ></View>


            </RelativeLayout>



        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

for that, you have to go with inflating option menu and menu.xml file will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/downloaded_pdf"
        android:title="@string/downloaded_pdf"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="#000"/>
</menu>
```

I hope this will help you're trying the wrong method, otherwise create your own app bar using custom layout

Answer (score 0):

In `RelativeLayout`, the last child in the XML overlays everything else that was defined previously. The problem you are facing here is because the Z-order of your XML is not what you need.

To fix this, you will need to move your `Button` declaration below the `AppBarLayout` declaration. Here is the code snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="apps.radwin.wintouch.activities.alignmentActivities.WorkordersSelectionActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_workorders_selection">

    <!--First declare the AppBarLayout-->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsLayoutWorkorderSelection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--Your button goes here just before the ViewPager-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/filterButtonMainWorkorderSelection"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_filter_list_black_24dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/workorderSelectionMainViewPagerContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

And the rest of your XML can remain the same.

**EDIT: You can take a look at this concept in more detail [here](https://vourkosa.github.io/android/2016/03/20/Working-with-overlays-Giving-birth-to-a-new-DecorView-child.html).**